# Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in Redhat

Tags: maven

When trying to build a maven project, following error is thrown:

> Could not find artifact
> com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in Redhat

I could find this artefact in the following repository:

https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/com/google/guava/guava-parent/30.1.0.redhat-00001/

So I've added it to my POM like so:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Redhat</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

However, the error still persists. I've already tried deleting my local `.m2` directory and doing a clean and forcing dependency updates with: `mvn -U clean install`.

Comment: That repository does not have version `31.1.0.redhat-00001`. Try specifying version `31.1.0.jre-redhat-00001` instead. Notice `.jre-` is inserted into that version.

Comment: @ChinHuang You are right. Unfortunately I do not know where this dependency is coming from. It must be a sub-dependency that I can not change.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by excluding all dependencies to Guava from any of my own dependencies as shown below.

```
<dependency>
   ...
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I then added a dependency to the Guava version on Central like so:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```